# What does the usage "in Donald Trump" mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, parentheticals

> A newly aggressive Russia under Vladimir Putin and, **in Donald Trump**, an American president who is unenthusiastic about both the EU and NATO, make this a terrible time for Europe to be weak and divided.
>
> *Can Europe be saved?* *[The Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21719462-if-it-survive-european-union-must-become-lot-more-flexible-can-europe-be-saved)* (25 March 2017)

Comment: It just gives a name to *an American president who is unenthusiastic about both the EU and NATO*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, does the preposition "in" mean "with reference to"?

Comment: "in Donald Trump" is a "parenthetical phrase", set off by commas.  This means that you can read the sentence without that phrase and it should make sense.  The sentence is poorly constructed, and the final comma probably doesn't belong there.

Comment: *in* here means *in the case of*,  so yes, *with reference to* is a close equivalent. (And *in the case of* can also be understood as *in the person of*, since in this example, the *case* or *matter* of who is the president is the *person*.)

Comment: Your answers were so satisfactory. Thank you so much.

Comment: "In the case of" works, but I think that it would be more precise to say that it represents "in the person of."  As @HotLicks says, the sentence has problems.  A simple solution would be to remove the "in" and all the commas.

Comment: [@Bakebake](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380043/what-does-the-usage-in-donald-trump-mean-in-the-following-sentence#comment894017_380043) Did you mean *satisfying*? *Satisfactory* sounds like 'only *just* good enough', but the rest of your comment sounded more appreciative. :)

Comment: I meant more than satisfying. Thank you for correcting my English!

Answer (score 1):

The sentence would be easier to read if "an American President" followed "and." In the writer's logic "Putin" and "an American President" are equal in importance, which is better expressed if they are not separated from each other.   Then various *in* phrases (or others) become possible.

> A newly aggressive Russia under Vladimir Putin and an American president, ***in the form of*** Donald Trump, who is unenthusiastic about both the EU and NATO, make this a terrible time for Europe to be weak and divided.

With this word order, alternatives to *in the form of* include, with slightly different nuances — the last two add irony — but essentially the same meaning:

*in this case*  /  *in the current situation*  /  *currently*  / *namely*  /  *none other than* /  *our very own*.

The words "an American president, *Donald Trump*," could also be used.

I favor *in the form of* because it is the only one of these that can be used without the preceding comma.  The sentence suffers from too many commas, and reads more easily as:

> A newly aggressive Russia under Vladimir Putin and an American president ***in the form of*** Donald Trump, who is unenthusiastic about both the EU and NATO, make this a terrible time for Europe to be weak and divided.